# Problems in a table: thickness of line, multicolumn, optimal height of rows

Tags: tables

I've written the following code, that produces the output I include below.

I have three problems:

1. The vertical line of the colored rows is finer than the rest of rows.
2. The first row of the table has 2 columns, that I want to combine in only one. Apparently, the row is multcolumn, but it separates the first letter of the rest. What is my error?
3. What is the better way to get the optimal height of every row, with some space before of the text, and some space after the text?

   ```
    \begin{table}[h]
       \centering
       \caption{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO}
       \begin{tabular}{|p{8cm}|p{8cm}|}
       \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{c}UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO\\\hline
   \cellcolor{green!20} Objetivos & \cellcolor{green!20} Criterios de evaluación \\\hline
    Identificar las partes del cuerpo. & 
    Diferencia las tres partes principales en las que se divide el cuerpo.\\\hline
   Distinguir las partes del cuerpo que están en la espalda de las que están en el frente. & 
   Localiza en sí mismo y en los demás las principales partes del cuerpo.\\\hline
   Diferenciar los estados de ánimo en las expresiones de la cara. & 
    Reconoce sus propias características físicas.\\\hline
   Distinguir los diferentes movimientos que podemos hacer con el cuerpo. &
   Identifica diferentes movimientos del cuerpo humano.\\\hline
   Reconocer y respetar las diferencias físicas existentes entre las personas. &
    Reflexiona sobre los cambios corporales de las personas a lo largo de la vida. \\\hline
   Identificar los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. & 
    Nombra los dedos de las manos. \\\hline
   Reconocer lesiones y medidas de protección corporal.  &
   Indica las posiciones derecha e izquierda; de frente, de espaldas y de lado en el cuerpo. \\\hline
    & Localiza en la cara diferentes órganos.\\\hline
    & Identifica lesiones y medidas de protección del cuerpo.\\\hline
   \cellcolor{green!20} Contenidos &
    \cellcolor{green!20} Competencias básicas \\\hline
   El cuerpo humano. & \\\hline
   Las partes del cuerpo humano. &
   Además de desarrollar la Competencia en el conocimiento e interacción con el mundo físico, en esta unidad se contribuye al desarrollo de las siguientes competencias:\\\hline
   Las articulaciones. &
    - Competencia cultural y artística.\\\hline
   Los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. &
    - Competencia lingüística.\\\hline
   Observación y obtención de información a partir de fotografías, dibujos y obras pictóricas. &
    - Autonomía e iniciativa personal.\\\hline
   Observación e imitación de posturas corporales. &
    - Competencia social y ciudadana\\\hline
   Interpretación de escenas secuenciadas cronológicamente. & \\\hline
   Respeto por todas las personas. & \\\hline
   Interés por realizar actividades físicas y deportivas. & \\\hline
   Fomento de actitudes tolerantes hacia las personas con discapacidades. &
   \\\hline
    & \\\hline
    & \\\hline
    & \\\hline
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
   ```

[image: Fragment of the output]

Comment: The `multicolumn` problem is fixed by grouping the contents of the cell between `{}`. For the other two problems I don't have an answer ready.

Comment: Effectively: multicolumn problem, solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently my comment solved it so to provide the answer:

`\multicolumn` takes three arguments: `\multicolum{<number of columns}{<alignment>}{<cell content>}`, if you don't group the contents of the cell only the first character of the contents is taken as the third argument to `\multicolumn` and the rest is assumed to belong in the next column.

Answer (score 2):

First problem is only viewer issue. However, if you want, you may increase the `\arrayrulewidth` → `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}`  Change the value as per need.

For second, follow what hugovdberg said.

For third, you have few options:

You may adjust the `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}`

You may add an invisible strut like `|>{\rule[-1ex]{0ex}{3.5ex}}p{8cm}|p{8cm}|`.

You may add extra space manually, like `\\[1ex]` after each line.

I prefer the first one.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}   %% put it here for making it global
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[htbp]
   \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
   \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}   % here it is local
    \centering
    \caption{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO}
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                   |>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO}\\\hline
\cellcolor{green!20} Objetivos & \cellcolor{green!20} Criterios de evaluación \\\hline
 Identificar las partes del cuerpo. &
 Diferencia las tres partes principales en las que se divide el cuerpo.\\\hline
Distinguir las partes del cuerpo que están en la espalda de las que están en el frente. &
Localiza en sí mismo y en los demás las principales partes del cuerpo.\\\hline
Diferenciar los estados de ánimo en las expresiones de la cara. &
 Reconoce sus propias características físicas.\\\hline
Distinguir los diferentes movimientos que podemos hacer con el cuerpo. &
Identifica diferentes movimientos del cuerpo humano.\\\hline
Reconocer y respetar las diferencias físicas existentes entre las personas. &
 Reflexiona sobre los cambios corporales de las personas a lo largo de la vida. \\\hline
Identificar los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. &
 Nombra los dedos de las manos. \\\hline
Reconocer lesiones y medidas de protección corporal.  &
Indica las posiciones derecha e izquierda; de frente, de espaldas y de lado en el cuerpo. \\\hline
 & Localiza en la cara diferentes órganos.\\\hline
 & Identifica lesiones y medidas de protección del cuerpo.\\\hline
\cellcolor{green!20} Contenidos &
 \cellcolor{green!20} Competencias básicas \\\hline
El cuerpo humano. & \\\hline
Las partes del cuerpo humano. &
Además de desarrollar la Competencia en el conocimiento e interacción con el mundo físico, en esta unidad se contribuye al desarrollo de las siguientes competencias:\\\hline
Las articulaciones. &
 - Competencia cultural y artística.\\\hline
Los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. &
 - Competencia lingüística.\\\hline
Observación y obtención de información a partir de fotografías, dibujos y obras pictóricas. &
 - Autonomía e iniciativa personal.\\\hline
Observación e imitación de posturas corporales. &
 - Competencia social y ciudadana\\\hline
Interpretación de escenas secuenciadas cronológicamente. & \\\hline
Respeto por todas las personas. & \\\hline
Interés por realizar actividades físicas y deportivas. & \\\hline
Fomento de actitudes tolerantes hacia las personas con discapacidades. &
\\\hline
 & \\\hline
 & \\\hline
 & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes:

I have adjusted the column widths so that they fit in. But your table is too long and you may be better off with `longtable`. Also add `[htbp]` instead of just `[h]` for the position specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution, with approximately the same vertical space above the text of a cell and below the text. A  more exact solution could be obtained with the `cellspace` package, as it defines a minimal amount of vertical space between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and similarly for the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell. Unfortunately, it seems to be incompatible with the `color` or `xcolor` packages.

So here is a hand-made solution, using both an `\extrarowheight` (which I set to 0.7ex) and an adjusted `invisible vertical rule` automatically inserted at the end of cells. This rule has depth 1.5ex, which seems correct, except in the first (title) row, that has a capitalised text for which 1.1ex looks better. Lengths measurement are in `ex` for it will make the adjustements independent of the font size — but probably not of the font family.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, textwidth = 15cm, textheight = 23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.7ex} %

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\caption{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.45\linewidth}<{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}}|p{0.45\linewidth}<{\rule[-1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}}|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c<{\rule[-1.1ex]{0pt}{1.1ex}}|}{UNIDAD DIDÁCTICA 1: NUESTRO CUERPO}\\\hline
\rowcolor{green!20}Objetivos\rule[-1.5ex]{0.6pt}{1.5ex} & Criterios de evaluación \\\hline%
 Identificar las partes del cuerpo.  &
 Diferenciar las tres partes principales en las que se divide el cuerpo.\\\hline
Distinguir las partes del cuerpo que están en la espalda de las que están en el frente. &
Localiza en sí mismo y en los demás las principales partes del cuerpo.\\\hline
Diferenciar los estados de ánimo en las expresiones de la cara. &
 Reconoce sus propias características físicas.\rule[-1.1ex]{0.6pt}{2.25ex}\\\hline
Distinguir los diferentes movimientos que podemos hacer con el cuerpo. &
Identifica diferentes movimientos del cuerpo humano.\\\hline
Reconocer y respetar las diferencias físicas existentes entre las personas. &
 Reflexiona sobre los cambios corporales de las personas a lo largo de la vida. \\\hline
Identificar los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. &
 Nombra los dedos de las manos. \\\hline
Reconocer lesiones y medidas de protección corporal.  &
Indica las posiciones derecha e izquierda; de frente, de espaldas y de lado en el cuerpo. \\\hline
 & Localiza en la cara diferentes órganos.\\\hline
 & Identifica lesiones y medidas de protección del cuerpo.\\\hline
\rowcolor{green!20}Contenidos & Competencias básicas \\\hline%
El cuerpo humano. & \\\hline
Las partes del cuerpo humano. &
Además de desarrollar la Competencia en el conocimiento e interacción con el mundo físico, en esta unidad se contribuye al desarrollo de las siguientes competencias:\\\hline
Las articulaciones. &
 - Competencia cultural y artística.\\\hline
Los cambios corporales con el paso del tiempo. &
 - Competencia lingüística.\\\hline
Observación y obtención de información a partir de fotografías, dibujos y obras pictóricas. &
 - Autonomía e iniciativa personal.\\\hline
Observación e imitación de posturas corporales. &
 - Competencia social y ciudadana\\\hline
Interpretación de escenas secuenciadas cronológicamente. & \\\hline
Respeto por todas las personas. & \\\hline
Interés por realizar actividades físicas y deportivas. & \\\hline
Fomento de actitudes tolerantes hacia las personas con discapacidades. &
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]